# After DDOS attack i cant access my site anymore

Tags: ddos

Hello guys I would like to ask for a help.

I just want to test my website for denial of service attack .
But it seem that i cant access my site 24hrs have been passed. Still nothing changed ..

This is the DDOS attack that i was downloaded.

```
https://github.com/Leetcore/JS-LOIC
```

Anyone can help me? Because i need to fix this.

Comment: My guess is your IP has been blocked - depending on how you carried out the attack (being from external servers or your own home connection). Try viewing your website on a device using mobile data or change your IP.

Comment: I would like to ask sir. That jsloic that i was downloaded is recommended for a testing?

Comment: @KarlChelton i already tried it sir.. viewing my website to device using mobile data. The result is the same .. Still cant access the website.

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: This is the url @KarlChelton http://philippineexplorer.com/

Comment: I tried to reset my server. But nothing change.

Comment: If you feed your URL to something like https://www.virustotal.com/ you see that no one can reach your site at the moment. Stackoverflow is about programming, so how exatcly does your question relate to that?

Comment: @Stein okay im just new in this community.. I will delete this post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things that could be wrong with your site that I have identified. I'll include them below but I recommend you **contact your web hosting provider** (which is shown as GoDaddy) and discuss the issue with them as they will be able to assist you further, and actually have the permissions to action any faults.

---

### DNS Updates

Your whois information was last updated 2019-05-29 @ 06:48:19, and it has not yet been a full 24 hours. DNS Propagation may be the problem.

### SOA Record - last update

Your SOA record appears to have updated in the last 24 hours, some time on 2019-05-29. Because it's been less than 24 hours, your domain name may not be working as expected due to DNS propagation.

### A Records (IP Addresses) - Hostname

Your domain name appears to be pointing to the following ip address / host:

✗ 50.62.22.174 - ip-50-62-22-174.ip.secureserver.net

### Apache

Apache does not appear to be running.

---

***TL;DR: Contact your web hosting provider.***

Comment: I just configure the dns servername today. But i was executed the ddos attack yesterday evening. I wait 12hrs before i access again in my website . And the result is still cannot access.